# Global variables in octave

Tags: global-variables, octave

I'm using GNU Octave, version 3.2.4.

I have two functions. First function, f1.m, has a global variable. I'm accessing the global variable in another function, f2.m.

It works fine in following situation:

```
# File f1.m
function testGlobal1()
    clear all;
    global var1 = [];
    testGlobal2();
endfunction

#File f2.m
function testGlobal2()
    global var1;
    isglobal("var1")
    var1
    var1 = [var1, 10]
endfunction
```

The result after running f1 is as follows:

> ans =  1
>   var1 = 
>   var1 =  10

Now, if I run f1 again, following is the result:

> ans =  1
>   var1 =  10
>   var1 =
>      10   10

Upon subsequent running of f1, the vector var1 continues to grow.

My question is, why isn't the variable, var1, getting reinitialized in f1 (line 3) even though the code session (is that what it's called?) is over and a new one begins when I run f1 again?

The funny thing is, if I assign a value to var1 in f2, instead of appending on the vector, the new value gets assigned to var1. Code for f2 with modifications is given below:

```
function f2()
    global var1;
    isglobal("var1")
    var1
    var1 = [var1, 10]
    var1 = 20
endfunction
```

The output after running f1 is below:

> ans =  1
>   var1 =
>      10   10
>   var1 =
>      10   10   10
>   var1 =  20

On running f1 again, following output is seen:

> ans =  1
>   var1 =  20
>   var1 =
>      20   10
>   var1 =  20

I get the code to behave as I expect it to if I reinitialize var1 to an empty vector in f2. In that case, subsequent running of f1 does not make var1 grow as shown above.

Could someone explain what's happening? Why doesn't the re initialization of var1 to empty vector in f1 work?

Comment: The Octave version you are using is very very old and no longer supported. It works when using a recent version of Octave (I'm using 4.0.1). It may have been a bug that has since been fixed or maybe `clear all` did not remove global variables.

Comment: I need to update my Linux distribution as well but waiting for my project to get over.  As you said, it might be fixed in latest versions of Octave. Thank you for replying.